# LINQ: select keys with given value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have `Dictionary<int key, int sum>`. I need select all keys where `sum==1`.

How I could do it with LINQ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `Where` to filter out key-value pairs by values and `Select` to narrow down key-value pairs to keys:

```
 var keys = myDictionary
   .Where(pair => pair.Value == 1)
   .Select(pair => pair.Key)
   .ToArray(); // if you want an array of these keys
```

Comment: Ok, i get IEnumerate object. How to get integer  from keys ?

Comment: @Mateusz Szymański: Well, you wanted "select all keys where `sum==1`" and my code enumerates them; you can add *materialization*, say, `ToArray()` - see my edit - if you want an array of such keys

Comment: All is ok. Thanks :)